# user process running at CPL0 privilege level

Tags: linux-kernel

Supposing we have a user process which always runs at CPL0 privilege level, I'm wondering if this is feasible: since this process is running at CPL0 privilege, it can access kernel structures and functions, then we use `get_current` function directly to get `task_struct` and change `euid` and `uid` to 0. Then we are root.
Is there anything wrong?

Comment: If something is running in ring0 usually people don't call it a user process ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply @AlexHoppus I achieve it by doing the following procedure. I add a call gate descriptor in LDT. My code will call it and then point back into user's process holding CPL0 privilege. In that case, my code will always run at CLP0 privilege level.

Comment: @AlexHoppus My question comes from isec.pl/papers/linux_kernel_do_brk.pdf IV. 5) privilege escalation part.

Comment: Supposing that you can control CPL0 process, yes, I think your reasoning is right.

Comment: @NemanjaBoric Thanks for your reply. In the last paragraph of [link](http://isec.pl/papers/linux_kernel_do_brk.pdf) IV. 5) privilege escalation part, if my reasoning is true, why do we need to "find task_struct somewhere within kernel memory and then change its UIDs" instead of using `get_current` directly? I got stuck on this problem for a long time. Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: @HuangJie, using `get_current` is not so simple as you think. You need to get address of that function somehow. Because of `always inline` modifier, this function is not shown by `/proc/kallsym`. So you need to search `find_symbol` function first, then use it for get address of `get_current`. From the other side, on x86 `task_struct` is stored just at fixed offset from address, stored in `sr0` register.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for your reply. So what you mean is that: in the last paragraph of [link](http://isec.pl/papers/linux_kernel_do_brk.pdf)  IV. 5) privilege escalation part, we can also use `get_current` method to change uid, but it is more complicate than finding the `task_struct` address. That's why we just scan the `task_struct` and change uid. Right? Thanks for patience.

Comment: I mean that using `get_current` is *not definitely simpler* than other ways for find address of `task_struct`. That's why article talk about general *finding the `task_struct` address*.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I'm sorry to bother you, but I can't figure out this question. It may sound a little bit stupid. Hope you don't mind :( Since we have used `mprotect` method which can change protection of almost any page in the kernel, then we can find `task_struct` and then write it, right? Why do we have to run at CPL0 privilege level first?

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot help with conditions on `mprotect` usage for kernel pages. Probably, it just refuses to change flags on these pages without corresponded priveleges.

Comment: You cannot just mprotect kernel pages if you don't have required permissions, and you don't have them if you are running outside of ring0. Further, mprotect on kernel pages has a potential to actually break stuff (depending how it is implemented), so i would not even use it. I don't see why would you even try to use it though. As for get_current, if you read sources you will see it depends on current_thread_info on your stack pointer (or gs register, i don't remember). But your userspace stack pointer (or gs) has nothing to od with kernel your kernel stack pointer, thus the macro is useless.

Comment: Finally, a bonus remark is that creds are not stored in task_struct for quite some time now. Instead, the struct stores a pointer to struct cred which actually contain your credentials.

Comment: @employeeofthemonthThanks for your reply. My question comes from [here](http://isec.pl/papers/linux_kernel_do_brk.pdf). After we are abel to expand our vma into kernel space, we can `mprotect` kernel pages. My question is: if we are able to change the protection of any kernel pages, we can find the `task_struct` address and change `uid`, right? But why does that material say we run at ring0 privilege level first?

Comment: You can, but you can't do that easily. "Legally" switching to ring0 makes the kernel also switch context giving easy access to your task_struct. Otherwise you have to read a lot of kernel sources and parse a lot of kernel memory to obtain such information.